# jQuery $.extend won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to create a jQuery plugin but I've run into numerous issues. Let me show you my code.

jQuery Plugin:

```
//This plugin was created by Ben Allen. Website: http://thebenallen.net/
//This plugin uses the OpenDyslexic font. Get it at: http://opendyslexic.org/
(function($) {

$.fn.dyslexicSupport = function( options ) {

    var settings = $.extend({
        //Defualt settings in case you break it.
        //backgroundColor       : 'white',
        //backgroundColorActive : '#BDBDBD',
        //color                 : 'black',
        //colorActive           : '#00143E',
        //alert                 : false,
        //fontStyle             : 'normal'

        backgroundColor       : 'white',
        backgroundColorActive : '#BDBDBD',
        color                 : 'black',
        colorActive           : '#00143E',
        alert                 : false,
        fontStyle             : 'normal'
    }, options);

    return this.each(function() {

        $("head").prepend("<style type=\"text/css\">" + 
                            "@font-face {\n" +
                                "\tfont-family: \"opendyslexic\";\n" + 
                                "\tsrc: url('http://dyslexicfonts.com/fonts/OpenDyslexic-Regular.otf');\n" + 
                                "\tfont-weight: normal;\n" +
                                "\tfont-style: normal;\n" +
                            "}\n" + 
                        "</style>");

        $("head").prepend("<style type=\"text/css\">" + 
                            "@font-face {\n" +
                                "\tfont-family: \"opendyslexic\";\n" + 
                                "\tsrc: url('http://dyslexicfonts.com/fonts/OpenDyslexic-Italic.ttf');\n" + 
                                "\tfont-weight: normal;\n" +
                                "\tfont-style: italic;\n" +
                            "}\n" + 
                        "</style>");

        $("head").prepend("<style type=\"text/css\">" + 
                            "@font-face {\n" +
                                "\tfont-family: \"opendyslexic\";\n" + 
                                "\tsrc: url('http://dyslexicfonts.com/fonts/OpenDyslexic-Bold.ttf');\n" + 
                                "\tfont-weight: normal;\n" +
                                "\tfont-style: bold;\n" +
                            "}\n" + 
                        "</style>");

        $(this).css('font-family', 'opendyslexic')

        //if(settings.fontStyle) {

            $(this).css('font-style', settings.fontStyle);

        //}

        if(settings.color) {

            $(this).css('color', color);

        }

        if(settings.backgroundColor) {

            $(this).css('background-color', settings.backgroundColor);

        }

        $(this).mouseenter(function() {

            if(settings.backgroundColorActive) {

                $(this).css('background-color', settings.backgroundColorActive);

            }

        });

        $(this).mouseleave(function() {

            if(settings.backgroundColor) {

                $(this).css('background-color', settings.backgroundColor);

            }

        });
        $(this).mouseenter(function() {

            if(settings.colorActive) {

                $(this).css('color', settings.colorActive);

            }

        });

        $(this).mouseleave(function() {

            if(settings.color) {

                $(this).css('color', settings.color);
            }

        });
            if(settings.alert == true) {

                $('document').ready(function() {

                    alert('This website is Dyslexia friendly.');

                });

            }

            else {

                return true;

            }

        $('#alertClose').click(function() {

            $('#alertDiv').hide()

        });
    });

}

}(jQuery));
```

How I call it in the HTML:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.dyslexicSupport.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('document').ready(function() {

            $('body').dyslexicSupport({
                backgroundColor       : 'white',
                backgroundColorActive : 'black',
                color                 : 'red',
                colorActive           : 'blue',
                alert                 : true,
                fontStyle             : 'italic'
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Ok, so let me explain what issues I'm having. The parameters when I call it won't override the default ones set in the .js file. Another issue is most options won't work. The only one that does is the `settings.fontStyle` option. I probably have so much more errors that I can't think of. But if anybody knows whats going on that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do this quick test. Add `console.log( options );` at the top and `console.log( settings )`. After you review the output, **do you still think the problem is `$.extend()`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the console you will spot the error, which is at

```
if(settings.color) {
    $(this).css('color', color);
}
```

It should be

```
if(settings.color) {
    $(this).css('color', settings.color);
}
```

otherwise the error causes all the following code to fail

---

See the fixed demo

```js
//This plugin was created by Ben Allen. Website: http://thebenallen.net/
//This plugin uses the OpenDyslexic font. Get it at: http://opendyslexic.org/
(function($) {

  $("head").prepend("<style type=\"text/css\">" +
        "@font-face {\n" +
        "\tfont-family: \"opendyslexic\";\n" +
        "\tsrc: url('http://dyslexicfonts.com/fonts/OpenDyslexic-Regular.otf');\n" +
        "\tfont-weight: normal;\n" +
        "\tfont-style: normal;\n" +
        "}\n" +
        "</style>");

      $("head").prepend("<style type=\"text/css\">" +
        "@font-face {\n" +
        "\tfont-family: \"opendyslexic\";\n" +
        "\tsrc: url('http://dyslexicfonts.com/fonts/OpenDyslexic-Italic.ttf');\n" +
        "\tfont-weight: normal;\n" +
        "\tfont-style: italic;\n" +
        "}\n" +
        "</style>");

      $("head").prepend("<style type=\"text/css\">" +
        "@font-face {\n" +
        "\tfont-family: \"opendyslexic\";\n" +
        "\tsrc: url('http://dyslexicfonts.com/fonts/OpenDyslexic-Bold.ttf');\n" +
        "\tfont-weight: normal;\n" +
        "\tfont-style: bold;\n" +
        "}\n" +
        "</style>");
  
  $.fn.dyslexicSupport = function(options) {

    var settings = $.extend({
      //Defualt settings in case you break it.
      //backgroundColor       : 'white',
      //backgroundColorActive : '#BDBDBD',
      //color                 : 'black',
      //colorActive           : '#00143E',
      //alert                 : false,
      //fontStyle             : 'normal'

      backgroundColor: 'white',
      backgroundColorActive: '#BDBDBD',
      color: 'black',
      colorActive: '#00143E',
      alert: false,
      fontStyle: 'normal'
    }, options);

    return this.each(function() {

      $(this).css('font-family', 'opendyslexic')
      //if(settings.fontStyle) {
      $(this).css('font-style', settings.fontStyle);
      //}

      if (settings.color) {
        $(this).css('color', settings.color);
      }

      if (settings.backgroundColor) {
        $(this).css('background-color', settings.backgroundColor);
      }

      $(this).mouseenter(function() {
        if (settings.backgroundColorActive) {
          $(this).css('background-color', settings.backgroundColorActive);
        }
      });

      $(this).mouseleave(function() {
        if (settings.backgroundColor) {
          $(this).css('background-color', settings.backgroundColor);
        }
      });
      
      $(this).mouseenter(function() {
        if (settings.colorActive) {
          $(this).css('color', settings.colorActive);
        }
      });

      $(this).mouseleave(function() {
        if (settings.color) {
          $(this).css('color', settings.color);
        }
      });
      
      if (settings.alert == true) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          alert('This website is Dyslexia friendly.');
        });
      } else {
        return true;
      }

      $('#alertClose').click(function() {
        $('#alertDiv').hide()
      });
      
    });
  }
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('body').dyslexicSupport({
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    backgroundColorActive: 'black',
    color: 'red',
    colorActive: 'blue',
    alert: true,
    fontStyle: 'italic'
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

How I call it in the HTML:
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But one more question. Is `if(settings.$VAR){}` needed?

Comment: it is a good idea to leave in, because if you run the `$(this).css('color', false)` or `$(this).css('color', '')`, it will remove any inline color applied on the element (*or any used styling property*).

Answer (score 0):

> ... most options won't work. The only one that does is the settings.fontStyle option. ...

That's because your default options and the ones you are sending to your plugin are the same except the `fontStyle`:

```
// Plugin settings
{
    backgroundColor       : 'white',
    backgroundColorActive : '#BDBDBD',
    color                 : 'black',
    colorActive           : '#00143E',
    alert                 : false,
    fontStyle             : 'italic'
}

// Code settings
{
    backgroundColor       : 'white',
    backgroundColorActive : '#BDBDBD',
    color                 : 'black',
    colorActive           : '#00143E',
    alert                 : true,            // Only these two
    fontStyle             : 'normal'         // are different!
}
```

**Update:**

`$.extend()` will amend the first object that is passed to it as an argument. So, you should be calling it like so:

```
var settings = {
    backgroundColor       : 'white',
    backgroundColorActive : '#BDBDBD',
    color                 : 'black',
    colorActive           : '#00143E',
    alert                 : false,
    fontStyle             : 'normal'
};
$.extend(settings, options);
```

---

There are other issues with your code. For example: you are adding several styles into `head` for each element in the selector. Probably, you don't want to do that.

Comment: Oh, sorry ;) . I forgot to mention the fact that I've changed it before. It won't work when I change it. I'll edit the question so it makes more sense.

Comment: I doubt that $.extend is not working. It amends the first object that was passed to it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Why wouldn't I want to add elements to `<head>`?

Comment: You would not want to add style to your head for every element in the selector. In other ways, if your call your extension like this `$('a'). dyslexicSupport();`, it would add your styles into your head the number of times that there are links in your page.